# Scale 2 images with different dimensions to the same one dimension

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I have 2 images with quite some different height and width.

I am fairly certain that I cannot have those images being scaled to the same one dimension with stretching or distorting at least one of the images. I am not cutting in either images.

It's seems logical to me that it's not possible, at least if we leave out the cutting part.

Am I right ? :)

Thanks

Comment: Yes? No? Depends? You need to be more specific. There are a lot of ways to merge two images, stitch them, overlay, etc, but you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, you are right.

If you've two images with differing dimensions (and differing aspect ratios) from one another, and neither of which have the same length and width (their aspect ratio is not 1:1) there is no logical geometric process by which they can be conformed to a single shared dimension - that predicates that the aspect ratio would be 1:1.

However, I'm sure from @Raphael's reluctance to simply say this, that they know, as do I, that what you can get away with depends entirely upon the *content* of the images and what you consider the *crucial information area* of each, and what exactly you mean by "not cutting in" to imagine a scenario in which it *might* be possible owing to cropping the overall images in such a way (but without cropping any crucial information areas) that they end up with the *same* aspect ratio as one another... and then you could scale them to be alike.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its also under some circumstances possible to extend one of the images to fit the other with some cloning and/or smart filling

Answer (score 2):

If the two images have the same *aspect ratio* (width divided by height) but different dimensions, you can just scale one of them to the size of the other and they should end up having the same dimensions.

If the two images have different aspect ratios they can only get the same dimensions if you:

1. Stretch image A to fit image B.
   [image]
2. Stretch image B to fit image A.
   [image]
3. Scale image A so it covers image B and trim away the excess.
   [image]
4. Scale image B so it covers image A and trim away the excess.
   [image]

In the last two cases of course you have some freedom to choose the best crop.

Comment: Now add a version where you add more background with the smart scale